# .load() works only first time but .ajax() works fine every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

The problem is because of slow network connections due to long distance access. The jQuery `.load()` function doesn’t seems to load the HTML page from second time and browser had ***canceled*** or ***aborted*** the request in about **500 ms** everytime. The same page when loaded using `.ajax()` is not causing a problem. Why jQuery `.load()` is been repeatedly aborted by the browser from second time? The response JSP page does contain several `.ajax()` requests. Is this causing problem from second time?

Comment: do you specify a timeout option while doing the ajax call?

Comment: `.load()` is just using an ajax call internally, but it has preset ajax parameters that you can't modify.  If you want to control these parameters, then you will have to use the ajax call and insert the content yourself.  So, that's a work-around for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jfriend00 I agree with you in using `.ajax()` with some timeout option.

Comment: Yes @ArunPJohny I have used timeout option in `.ajax()` call. My question was why `.load()` is not working for the consecutive time. Anyway I got the answer. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ajaxSetup()` before calling `load()` to set timeout

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 30000
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 0):

**Please check timeout parameter**

[Referance](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/u3f9C/1415/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/test_ajax_timeout/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 15,
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(t);
        }
    }
});
```

If you changed timeout above a limit you will see error. You can set up an error callback as showed below

```
$.ajax({}).error(function(){ // Code });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using `.ajaxSetup()` before calling `.load()`  as recommended by @Chang

But I would like to use `.ajax()` call with some desired timeout instead of using `.load()` because the `.ajaxSetup()` is not recommended to use since it is used to configure default ajax options.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/